# accessing data from child stateful widgets

Tags: flutter

In short: I have a stateful widget that contains another stateful widget with a variable and I would like to access that variable from the parent but I cannot find a way without using a provider (which I want to avoid to keep the layout and the data separated). Is there a way to achieve that?

In long: I am trying to create a tool where a person can enter a couple of school grades and get the average of them. To enter the grades I am using buttons and I give the user a row of possible grades (from A* to U) and the user can click on a plus Icon button to add another row. The entire widget is one stateful widget so that rows can be added and removed dynamically and each row is also a stateful widget to only select one of the grades and highlight the color. The whole thing looks like this:
[image]

The system works well so far except that I now want to calculate the average grade of the selected grades. For that I need to access the selected grade in each of the rows and I cannot think of a good way to do it. I know this could be done by using a provider but I would rather avoid that since the average grade is purely visual and I want to keep the design and the data part as separated as possible.

My code for the container widget:

```
class GradeSection extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GradeSectionState createState() => _GradeSectionState();
}

class _GradeSectionState extends State<GradeSection> {
  int numGrades = 3;

  Widget avgGrade() {
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
        color: Colors.grey,
        child: Center(child: Text('average grade here')),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: [
          for (var i in List.generate(numGrades, (index) => index))
            ButtonBox(i),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              avgGrade(),
              IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                  onPressed: () => setState(() => numGrades++)),
              numGrades > 0
                  ? IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.remove),
                      onPressed: () => setState(() => numGrades--))
                  : Container(),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The code for each row:

```
class ButtonBox extends StatefulWidget {
  final int index;
  ButtonBox(this.index);

  @override
  _ButtonBoxState createState() => _ButtonBoxState();
}

class _ButtonBoxState extends State<ButtonBox> {
  String selectedButton = 'B';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
        color: Colors.grey,
      ),
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
      child: Row(
        children: ['A*', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'U']
            .map(
              (e) => Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    style: ButtonStyle(
                        backgroundColor: selectedButton != e
                            ? MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.grey)
                            : MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.blue)),
                    onPressed: () => setState(() => selectedButton = e),
                    child: Text(e),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
            .toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

edit: I did achieve the functionality by not creating a child stateful widget and instead used a map in the parent widget with the index as key and the grade as value. But knowing the solution to the original problem would be really useful in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is basically one of state management. If you don't want to use any external packages InheritedWidget allow you to pass state around. However it's likely that you will be more happy by using an external library like [BloC](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) or [riverpod](https://riverpod.dev/) for state management.